# Android OnTouchListner issue

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I am trying to implement the `onTouch` event in my program but it is not working. I'm doing it in a simple manner but it is not happening. My code is:

```
    public class VideosActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView image;
    FirstView fview;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.videos_layout);
        //image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
       fview = new FirstView(this);
       setContentView(fview);
    }
     public class FirstView extends View implements OnTouchListener{

        public FirstView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            image.setOnTouchListener(this);
        }


         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.dna2);
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

In my program is showing following error.my stack is pasted here...

```
    05-02 12:43:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(358): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 12:43:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(358): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidtablayout/com.example.androidtablayout.VideosActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 12:43:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(358):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
05-02 12:43:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(358):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2503)
05-02 12:43:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(358):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
05-02 12:43:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(358):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
05-02 12:43:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(358):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:651)
05-02 12:43:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(358):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:323)
05-02 12:43:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(358):  at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:129)
05-02 12:43:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(358):  at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:453)
05-02 12:43:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(358):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
05-02 12:43:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(358):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
05-02 12:43:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(358):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-02 12:43:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(358):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-02 12:43:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(358):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-02 12:43:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(358):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-02 12:43:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(358):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 12:43:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(358):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-02 12:43:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(358):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-02 12:43:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(358):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-02 12:43:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(358):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 12:43:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(358): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 12:43:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(358):  at com.example.androidtablayout.VideosActivity$FirstView.<init>(VideosActivity.java:33)
05-02 12:43:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(358):  at com.example.androidtablayout.VideosActivity.onCreate(VideosActivity.java:25)
05-02 12:43:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(358):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-02 12:43:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(358):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
05-02 12:43:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(358):  ... 18 more
05-02 13:23:21.845: E/AndroidRuntime(515): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 13:23:21.845: E/AndroidRuntime(515): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidtablayout/com.example.androidtablayout.VideosActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 13:23:21.845: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
05-02 13:23:21.845: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2503)
05-02 13:23:21.845: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
05-02 13:23:21.845: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
05-02 13:23:21.845: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:651)
05-02 13:23:21.845: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:323)
05-02 13:23:21.845: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:129)
05-02 13:23:21.845: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:453)
05-02 13:23:21.845: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
05-02 13:23:21.845: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
05-02 13:23:21.845: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-02 13:23:21.845: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-02 13:23:21.845: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-02 13:23:21.845: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-02 13:23:21.845: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 13:23:21.845: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-02 13:23:21.845: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-02 13:23:21.845: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-02 13:23:21.845: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 13:23:21.845: E/AndroidRuntime(515): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 13:23:21.845: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at com.example.androidtablayout.VideosActivity$FirstView.<init>(VideosActivity.java:35)
05-02 13:23:21.845: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at com.example.androidtablayout.VideosActivity.onCreate(VideosActivity.java:26)
05-02 13:23:21.845: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-02 13:23:21.845: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
05-02 13:23:21.845: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  ... 18 more
```

my xml file is as follow ...

```
<TableLayout
      android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

      <TableRow
          android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
          <TextView android:text="pic on click which will tell where is the dna located in human body or cell "
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      </TableRow>

      <TableRow
          android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/imageView1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:src="@drawable/dna1" />

      </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `image` object that your use in the constructor of `FirstView` is never assigned a valid object and when you try to use it is throws the `NullPointerException`. If the `ImageView` is in the layout that you commented(`R.layout.videos_layout`) out then it should be:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.videos_layout);
image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.the_id_of_the_imageview_fromThe_layout);
fview = new FirstView(this);
setContentView(fview);
```

Otherwise you have to make sure you assign a valid `ImageView` object to the `image` reference.

**Edit :**
The above code will work, I don't know why you decided to put:

```
image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

in the constructor of `fview`(this will throw the `NullPointerException` again). The correct code that works is:

```
//...
    public class VideosActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView image;
    FirstView fview;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.videos_layout);
        image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        fview = new FirstView(this);
        setContentView(fview);
    }
     public class FirstView extends View implements OnTouchListener{

        public FirstView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            image.setOnTouchListener(this);
        }
//...
```

Also I don't think that you understand what you are doing and you should revise the code you are writing. You:

- set the contentView with a layout that has an `ImageView`.
- you then construct a simple view that implements the `OnTouchListener` and in this view's constructor you set the view that you are just building as the listener for the `ImageView` from the previous layout(what are you trying to do?!?!).
- you than replace the first layout with the `fview`(that is empty and you'll not see anything)

The code that you posted will show a blank screen as the `fview` is the final view that will be shown in the activity and the listener that you set for the `ImageView` is useless because the `ImageView` is not on the screen anymore.

Once again I recommend you to improve your code.

Comment: @monu you're not assigning `image` a value, and Lukspog has told you how to do that. Besides just posting "it is not working", how about saying what about it is not working? Otherwise this will be an extremely long back and forth which will just frustrate both parties.

Answer (score 0):

You should init image variable first: 
`image= (ImageView ) findViewById(R.id.imageview);`

then call `fview = new FirstView(this);`

Comment: if imageview is not generated from xml layout, you shoud create new instance of imageview: image = new imageview(context) in construction of FirstView. then call image.setOnTouchListener(this);

Answer (score 0):

use this line in your oncreate hope it will help

```
image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.your_image_view_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you create new View called fview, but don't implement it, so java don't know what is in there.

```
fview = new FirstView(this);
setContentView(fview);
```

You have to make layout with ImageView in it (or use your created) and use that layout, so there you can use your image. Now your image is floating somewhere, but not in your view

Also, your image is not created - it is null or worse - some garbage. This code is real mess and won't work. I recommend you to read at least first chapters of Android Documentation to learn about acitivies, layouts and other basic stuff: http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html